# Como modificar valores de un PLC desde un formulario html?

Tags: php, html

Estoy desarrollando un sistema para controlar un PLC Siemens S7 1200 la cosa es que estoy mirando y no encuentro nada al respecto, tengo un formulario es html/php con un input text con el nombre 'EMERGENCIA' y el plc tiene una variable BOOL del mismo nombre. la cuestion es que nunca he tocado un PLC alguien puede decirme si existe alguna forma de hacer esto desde php o algo similar?

Comment: No tengo ni idea, pero buscando he encontrado [una página](https://www.infoplc.net/descargas/103-siemens/automatas/s7-1200) con muchos documentos de ejemplo. Y este [otro documento](http://www.infoplc.net/files/descargas/siemens/infoplc_net_the_guide_about_tcpip_connections_between_pcs_and_siemens_plcs.pdf) donde trata de leer la información del PLC mediante VB.NET, lo cual indica que lo puedes adaptar a PHP.

Comment: Mirate estas dos páginas a ver si te sirven. [En esta página](https://electronicaymanufactura.blogspot.com/2016/09/uso-del-servidor-web-integrado-en-el.html) muestran un poco la estructura del PLC S7 1200 y como activar el servidor web. [En esta otra página](https://johanneskinzig.de/index.php/software-development/18-restful-api-for-simatic-s7-1200-plc-python-client) muestran como interactuar con el PLC S7 1200 mediante servicios REST y Python (y si tienes problemas con Python siempre se puede traducir a otro idioma).